# fullCalendar time and date format symfony 3.0

Tags: javascript, symfony, calendar, fullcalendar, adminlte

I am junior in development and my mission is to make an agenda for doctors where they will be able to enter new appointments, view their planning, etc.

I am trying to do so with AdminLTE and Full Calendar on Symfony 3.0. The version of Full Calendar used by AdminLTE was 2.2.5.
As I needed my Calendar to return the list of events for a day ("listDay") and the older version did not implement this function, I updated Full Calendar version to v3.4.0.

Now I am having trouble with the axisFormat (timeFormat) et dateFormat.
I would like the date to be displayed like : day/month/year (e.g: 13/06/2017 or mar. 13/06) and the time like : HH:mm (e.g: 15h20 and not 3:pm).
But for now, the date and time are displayed like :

view of my calendar
[image: [1]]

I found a lot of solutions on the web and when my calendar is not on Symfony, the code works fine.
  Does anybody have an idea of what I could do to solve my issue ? Here is the code content of my own js file :

```
<section class="content">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                                <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                                <div id="calendar"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /. box -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                   {# <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="box box-solid">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <h4 class="box-title">Motifs de consultation</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <!-- type de consultations -->
                                <div id="legende">
                                    <div class="bg-green">Première consultation</div>
                                    <div class="bg-yellow">Visite de contrôle</div>
                                    <div class="bg-aqua">Chirurgie réfractive</div>
                                    <div class="bg-light-blue">Rééducation visuelle</div>
                                    <div class="bg-red">Urgences</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /. box -->
                    </div>#}
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </section>
```

Comment: Edit : solution for my time format --> slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm" in my js file.   
Now let's find for the date format displayed on top :D 
(it took me 2 days to ask the question here and I found one part of the solution few minutes after...)

Comment: Edit : solution for my date format --> columnFormat: 'ddd D/MM' !! 
I solved it alone but if one day someone has the same issue, well I hope that will help :)